# how to make file alignment using fprintf in c?

Tags: c, stdio

i have  problem in aligning the file using C

program line :

```
    fprintf(fpscrip,"\n %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld , %ld",scripCode,tradeVolume,LTQ,LTR,OpenRate,CloseRate,HighRate,LowRate,TotBuyQty,To‌​tSellQty,LowerCircuitLimit,UpperCircuitLimit)
```

file o/p

```
524667 , 7 , 1 , 34010 , 34500 , 34825 , 34500 , 34010 , 728 , 698 , 27865 
 533573 , 83625 , 50 , 14260 , 13655 , 13595 , 14440 , 13575 , 9202 , 15989 , 10880
```

The result should print like :-

```
524667 ,  7  , 1 ,... 
533573 ,83625,50,...
```

Comment: What kind of alignment you want and where is your code?

Comment: Well maybe you should **calculate** spaces and offsets when printing to make sure the alignment is okay.... Or you use a format specifier for `fprintf` to pad the numbers as you wish. Something like `%05d` should do.

Comment: Note that your format string has __11__ format specifiers but you are passing __12__ values.

Comment: yup i noted now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As like `printf()` You need to use some left and right alignments

`printf()`  write output to stdout

`fprintf()` write output to the given output stream;

`printf("%6d",num);` `// if num  have 3 digits then adds three more spaces at left of num.`

like this only you need to use with `fprintf()`

In your file you have only 6 digits in the maximum number.

replace all `%ld` with `%7ld` and add \n after every 3 or 4 numbers to get perfect allignment

```
fprintf(fpscrip,"\n %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld , %7ld ",scripCode,tradeVolume,LTQ,LTR,OpenRate,CloseRate,HighRate,LowRate,TotBuyQty,To‌​tSellQty,LowerCircuitLimit,UpperCircuitLimit);
```